# Using Gstreamer with Google speech API (Streaming Transcribe) in C++

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, gstreamer, grpc, google-speech-api

I am using the Google Speech API from cloud platform for getting speech-to-text of a streaming audio. I have already done the REST API calls using curl `POST` requests for a `short audio file` using GCP.

I have seen the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) of the Google Streaming Recognize, which says **"Streaming speech recognition is available via gRPC only."**

I have gRPC (also protobuf) installed in my **OpenSuse Leap 15.0**. Here is the screenshot of the directory.

[image: Directory]

Next I am trying to run the streaming_transcribe example from [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api), and I found that the sample program uses a local file as the input but simulate it as a microphone input (catching 64K chunks sequentially) and then send the data to Google server.

For initial tests to check the grpc is correctly set on my system I ran `make run_tests`. I have changed the Makefile as:

```
...
...Some text as original Makefile
...
.PHONY: all
all: streaming_transcribe
googleapis.ar: $(GOOGLEAPIS_CCS:.cc=.o) 
      ar r $@ $?
streaming_transcribe: streaming_transcribe.o parse_arguments.o googleapis.ar
      $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
run_tests:
      ./streaming_transcribe -b 16000 resources/audio.raw
      ./streaming_transcribe --bitrate 16000 resources/audio2.raw
      ./streaming_transcribe resources/audio.flac
      ./streaming_transcribe resources/quit.raw
clean: rm -f *.o streaming_transcribe \
       googleapis.ar \
       $(GOOGLEAPIS_CCS:.cc=.o)
```

This **do not** work well (neither does the orignal Makefile). 
But the `streaming_transcribe.o` file is created after running the Makefile. So I manually ran the file and got the following responses

[image: Screenshot2]

Any suggestions on how to run the test and use gstreamer instead of the function used for simulating the mic-phone audio?

Comment: You can't execute plain object files. They need to be linked (which is what the line starting with `sreaming_transcribe:` is for) - but `make` is picky. The `$(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@` line for linking `streaming_transcribe` must start with a tab character.

Comment: Hi @TedLyngmo The suggestions given above are already taken care of. But I am still getting the error. the `LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib 'pkg-config --libs grpc++ grpc' -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--no-as-needed -lprotobuf -lpthread -ldl`

Comment: Ok, then update your question and include the exact error you get (as text, not as an image).

Comment: I am trying to re-install everything. I will let you know the output

Comment: Reinstalling from scratch really solved the problem. Apparently the shared objects were not set up correctly  which stopped the the `make run_tests` to go through. Running `*.o` file was not correct anyway. The Makefile produces the executable which needs to be run. **How do I mark this issue close?**

Comment: Hmm, I think your only options are to delete the question or provide an answer to it that you accept. In this case, deleting it seems to be the best option.

Comment: I am keeping this issue open AS the title says "How to use google speech api " which is general. So anything that Might come ahead can be added in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to run the test

Follow the instructions on [cpp-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples). *Prerequisit* - Install [grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc), [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf), and [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) and setup the environment as said in the links above.

> gstreamer instead of the function used for simulating the mic-phone audio

For this program I have created pipelines which are

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/file/FOO.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,depth=16,width=16,rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay  ! udpsink host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=yyyy
```

*The audio file can be changed to flac or mp3 with changing appropriate elemnets in pipeline*

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=yyyy ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE ! filesink location=/path/to/where/you/want/to/dump/the/rtp/payloads/ABC.raw
```

The process of taking payloads from rtp stream and writing it on file is done in another thread than sending the data to google and reading the response.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a dedicated soundcard can listen to rtsp stream? with

```
try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create

RecognitionConfig config =
    RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
        .setLanguageCode("en-US")
        .setSampleRateHertz(44100)
        .setAudioChannelCount(2)
        .setEnableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel(true)
        .build();
```

Comment: Hey @zip Have you tried this? Well, I am not sure where to begin with! I found that the sample takes some data from the google storage and simulate it as  audio content arriving from a microphone input (audio in 64k chunks at a time). I want to see if I can change this and put the RTP payload data instead.

Comment: Hey @zip. Let me correct myself from the above comment. The example doesnot take the audio file from google storage, rather it is a local audio file. I have done the similar thing using Gstreamer framework to simulate rtp streaming.