# Audio to text is slow and words are getting dropped

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I have a code which takes videos from an input folder, converts it into audio file(.wav) using ffmpeg. 
It then converts the audio file to text by recording 30 seconds audio (dura=30) and converting it to text using google translate api.

The problem is that the code takes a lot of time to convert video to text and it drops first two words and some words after every 30 seconds.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys
import shutil
from googletrans import Translator
from pathlib import Path
import os
import wave
def audio_to_text(self,video_lst,deploy_path,video_path,audio_path):
    try:
        txt_lst=[]
        for video_file in video_lst:
            file_part=video_file.split('.')
            audio_path_mod = audio_path +'/'+ '.'.join(file_part[:-1])
            dir_path=video_path+'.'.join(file_part[:-1])
            self.createDirectory(audio_path_mod)
            audio_file='.'.join(file_part[:-1])+'.wav'
            command_ffmpeg='set PATH=%PATH%;'+deploy_path.replace('config','script')+'audio_video/ffmpeg/bin/'
            command='ffmpeg -i '+video_path+'/'+video_file+' '+audio_path_mod+'/'+audio_file
            os.system(command_ffmpeg)
            os.system(command)
            r=sr.Recognizer()
            dura=30
            lang='en'
            wav_filename=audio_path_mod+'/'+audio_file

            f = wave.open(wav_filename, 'r')
            frames = f.getnframes()
            rate = f.getframerate()
            audio_duration = frames / float(rate)
            final_text_lst=[]
            counter=0

            with sr.AudioFile(wav_filename) as source:
                while counter<audio_duration:
                    audio=r.record(source,duration=dura)
                    counter+=dura
                    try:
                        str=r.recognize_google(audio)
                        final_text_lst.append(str)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
            print('Text data generated..')

            text_path=audio_path_mod+'/'+audio_file.replace('.wav','_audio_text.csv')
            with open(text_path, 'w') as f:
                f.write(' '.join(final_text_lst))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Any help/suggestion would be valuable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm mostly converting educational speeches

Comment: Hey Madhur, This is an interesting application. Would be you open to share details on video to audio conversion?  You may want to use a simple gstreamer pipeline for that and _you can simply add subtitles to it in the pipeline itself_, or you can use the audio file generated with it to put in gRPC speech recognition sample given online. [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514814/using-gstreamer-with-google-speech-api-streaming-transcribe-in-c) for how I did it. It is similar to what you are trying. Let me know if you want to use this approach.

Comment: Is there a progress?